# How to design an auto-increment field while allowing manual user input?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

The `Client` table:

```
Id (PK), int, not null (IDENTITY)
NoClient, int, not null
```

The form (wireframe):

[image]

- The field NoClient should be a number
- The field NoClient should be unique
- The field NoClient should be auto-generated if null
- The field NoClient is for reference only
- The field NoClient is NOT the primary key
- The field NoClient is NOT the identity column

How to solve that problem SQL-wise?

**EDIT.** I'm talking about the `NoClient` column, not `ID`.

Comment: Add another column to your table. The database is does not allow this for a reason.

Comment: Make it nullable, add an insert trigger that fills it if it's null.

Comment: Why you want to allow users to set the pk? How would they know if the number is already in use?

Comment: @Oscar read my requirements. This is not the PK.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, I would recommend against using nullable for a column that should never actually end up null.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks. Best idea so far.. did you find my question unclear somewhat? Just curious.

Comment: @KirkWoll agreed. Actually, I just tested it, and the column can be `not null` if the "instead of" insert trigger handles the null value

Comment: @maxbeaudoin a little bit, yeah - it would have been clearer if you typed out the requirements rather than posting an image, and made it very explicit that you are talking about the `NoClient` column, not `ID`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly interpreting those rules, there is no solution.  One of those rules is either not correct, or not precise.  You can't solve it with an AFTER trigger, because you can't attempt to insert a blank into a numeric field, nor can you with a BEFORE trigger.  You can't use a default either.

Now, if you mean that "when left blank" means "when left null", then you can solve it with a very carefully crafted BEFORE TRIGGER.  (Or an AFTER TRIGGER, if you can change the field to a nullable int)

If you mean that "when left blank" means that you don't mention the column in your insert/update, then you might be able to get by with a carefully crafted default, by converting a call to GUID via NewID to a very large number.

As a side note, I would tell the designer to go back and redesign it, because whatever solution you do finally come up with, it is not very scalable, and a PITA to do correctly.  You have to basically lock the entire table (from reading and writing), do an entire table/index scan to make sure the value you come up with is UNIQUE.  You probably should be using the ID field as the client no, possibly seeding the identity with something not starting with 0.

Comment: I suppose you could create a second table that just has an identity in it, and during the `before trigger` (I assume you can do this), insert a row into it, retrieve the last identity created, and assign it to the clientno field, and do that for each row attempting to be inserted.  Probably better than locking the client table exclusively.  Or talk the designer into making clientno a nullable field, and doing it in an `AFTER TRIGGER`, which is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Execute a query to [SET IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) OFF first, insert, your ID, then SET IDENTITY ON again.